# What's the point of IPS benchmarking in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, benchmarking

I've been search for `iterations per second` benchmark explanation on Google, and Ruby seems to be the only language with a [popular library](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips) where this concept is utilized. Can someone explain, what is the whole point of IPS benchmarking, in what kind of situation would you find it useful?

Answer (score -1):

Benchmarking is important, but determining the number of runs runs to get a relevant result by hand is time consuming and boring.

The author of this gem is the author of Rubinius, an implementation of Ruby itself. This IPS thing is nothing special, just an automated way of determining an agreeable number of runs (and run them).